# Usar função jQuery apenas em @media screen and (max-width:960px)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider, media-queries

Sabemos que existem as `@media queries`.

Elas funcionam com CSS.

Mas preciso fazer com JavaScript.

Preciso que o bxSlider funcione apenas em `@media screen and (max-width:960px)`.

Comment: Poste sua solução como resposta então (e quando o período mínimo de espera se passar, aceite).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Então galera, fiz da seguinte forma e resolveu meu problema:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   if( $(window).width() <= 960){
     jQuery('.img-parceiros').bxSlider({
        nextSelector: '.seta-dir',
        prevSelector: '.seta-esq',
        nextText: '',
        prevText: '',
        auto: false,
        slideWidth: 200,
        minSlides: 2,
        maxSlides: 2,
        pager:false
     });
   }
});
```

Comment: Prefiro a resposta do Diniz, é mais específica..

Comment: De fato, essa solução resolve metade do problema (o `max-width`), mas se o media não for `screen` o `bxSlider` será ativado incorretamente.

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma que pode ser feito é usando o [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.matchMedia).

Por exemplo:

```
if (window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 960px)').matches){
  document.write('<script src="../js/bxSlider.js"></script>');
}
```

Lembrando que não cheguei a testar, mas na teoria deve funcionar.

Dar uma olhada nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7640666/2161286) que deverá funcionar para outros navegadores.

Comment: Não parece funcionar... http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/rs4tK/ (fiz algo errado?)

Comment: Aqui funcionou. Escreveu o teste normal. Verifique o navegador, pois nativamente só acima do IE10, entre outros.

Comment: Escreveu o `teste` quando **está** nas condições propostas, mas **não escreveu** o `teste` quando **não está** nessas condições?

Comment: Achei o erro! O `window.matchMedia` não retorna `true` ou `false`, mas um objeto complexo (`MediaQueryList`). Se você substituir seu `if` por `window.matchMedia(...).matches` aí funciona corretamente: http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/rs4tK/1/

Comment: P.S. Agora que vi que seu link também dá a solução correta... :P (vou sugerir uma edição na sua resposta então, e dar o merecido +1)

Comment: Valew @mgibsonbr e muito boa sua observação e correção.